# Appending static text to the first index of data within ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Say I am looping through data into a table using ejs. How can I append some text to the data within the first row of the table

for example:

```
<tbody class="scroll" id="upcoming__body">
    <% data.forEach((record) => { %>
    <tr>
          <td>
          <% if(record.moneyReceived[0]) { %>
          <span>received</span>
          <% } %>
          <span style="display:block; font-size: 16pt; color:green;">$<%=record.moneyReceived%></span>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
<% }) %>
```

If my template loops through the data 10 times that I will have 10 rows of this block of code. I want the first row within that td to have a text appended "received". I wrote an if statement above to try to get this effect but have not been successful. Any ideas?

Comment: where is the loop part ?

Comment: updated the code to include the for each loop

Comment: thanks. check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `.forEach` loop you get the index as second parameter. So, you can add a check if it's the first index like

```
<% if(index == 0){ %>
```

This is how your code should look like

```
<tbody class="scroll" id="upcoming__body">
    <% data.forEach((record, index) => { %>
    <tr>
          <td>
          <% if(index == 0){ %>
          <span>received</span>
          <% } %>
          <span style="display:block; font-size: 16pt; color:green;">$<%=record.moneyReceived%></span>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
<% }) %>
```